# BigQuery to Kafka as a source

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery

I have a streaming data from webpages that is loaded in to BigQuery and I want to connect the BigQuery to Kafka as a source.
Is there any connector like kafka-connect that is used for BigQuery sink.

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 2):

For BigQuery to Kafka, I could not find any direct API. However, you can export data in BigQuery via [1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in_bigquery) or [Python Client for Google BigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/bigquery)
 . Then, you can use [Kafka Python client](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python)
 to import data to Kafka.

For Kafka to BigQuery, [Kafka Connect BigQuery Connector](https://github.com/wepay/kafka-connect-bigquery) and  [bigquery-kafka-connect](https://github.com/nodefluent/bigquery-kafka-connect) are the common sink connectors from Apache Kafka to Google BigQuery.

For more information please check [Loading data from Kafka into BigQuery with Kafka Connect](https://wecode.wepay.com/posts/kafka-bigquery-connector).

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the answer. I could not find any direct API from BigQuery to Kafka.

Comment: thanks Shahin, I'm looking for direct push within cloud or a connector for the same. I don't want to write a poller,

Comment: I cannot find any direct push for that. I think for getting data from BigQuery you need to submit a Query. So, it is a bit different from the typical data transfers.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested / used it, but Google has partnered with Simba to provide ODBC and JDBC drivers for bq. This could possibly be used with the JDBC connector?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer would be more useful and long-lasting if you include the relevant specific content of the link directly in your answer. It makes it easier and faster for users to make use of your answer and also guards against the link changing or dying.